# Make mobile hotspot's wifi appear as mobile data in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, download, mobile-hotspot

A windows application starts downloading large files when connected to wifi irrespective of what user choose. When connected to mobile data, the application downloads only when user select/allow.

Usually I connect laptop to mobile hotspot, which has limited data.

In other to avoid massive downloading, is there any application that can fake the mobile hotspot's wifi as data connection in windows.

Edit 1:
Even after setting wifi as metered connection, the application keep downloading the files.

Comment: You can configure any network connection as having limited data even a mobile hotspot

Comment: Also, make sure the app doing the download can be restarted at a different time / different connection. Some apps can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set any connection as a metered. It's a built-in Windows feature. No need to "fake" anything.

1. Right-click the networking icon in the notification area (bottom right part of the screen). Select *Open Network & Internet settings*.
2. Click *Properties* next to the connection you want to edit.
3. Toggle *Set as metered connection* to *On*.

Comment: Even after setting wifi as metered connection, the application keep downloading the files. Problem not solved.

Comment: @sadiqeen That means that the program in question doesn't check/respect the metered connection setting. Your question implies that it does though.

Comment: I am looking for an app that can fake hotspot's wifi as mobile data connection.

Comment: If the application only honors connection type, as hinted by @gronostaj, an (also native) alternative would be setting up a Bluetooth PAN (Personal Area Network): it *won’t* have the same performance as wifi *nor* will allow others sharing the hotspot but may increase (laptop/mobile) battery stamina as Bluetooth is more power-efficient.